# How Can I install oci8 drivers in php 5.3 on my windows pc whith out xampp or wamp

Tags: oracle11g, windows-7-x64, php-5.3, apache2.2

```
Win 2007 Server 32bit
Apache2.2
PHP version 5.3.14 which was without php_oci8 files
oracle Enterprise Edition installed
```

I need to be able to connect to remote oracle database, so I find out, that OCI8 extension should be used. To make OCI8 work, I also should need at least Oracle Instant Client on server, because of certain DLL OCI8 need.

What I did?

```
downloaded Oracle Instant Client from their sites ( oracle download site ), version 11.2.0.4.0
unpacked into folder, I choosed Program Files/oci_11_2
added to windows variable path the address
restarted Win
downloaded php_oci8 libraries from PECL ( PECL oci8 dl site )
put them into the ext directory set in php.ini
added extension=php_oci8.dll into php.ini
restarted apache
```

After all this I checked php_info to see, if everything is ok, however no signs of oci8.

I tried older Oracle instant client, swtiching between php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll or php_oci8_12c.dll, yet nothing helped.

Currently, I have no idea what to do, unless trying reinstalling php(which I don't want to because of many problematics connected with that), different Oracle instant clients or differenct php_oci8 libraries. I google for some hours, tried looking on Stack, but no solution, just some tips, that didn't help. Have someone encountered and solved something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got to set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH Apache environment variables too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. set ORACLE_HOME to point to the Instant Client root folder,
2. enable PHP_OCI8_SOMETHING.DLL in your PHP.INI config (... which you did),
3. restart Windows, ideally,
4. start Apache.

... and it should work.

**Ideally** you would do this under the Windows account which owns+runs the Apache+PHP server (which should be other than that which you use regularly; this way you can have several Oracle homes concurrently in use on your Windows), so one more ...

5. check the filesystem privileges - whether the Instant Client is accessible to the Apache process.